# Primefaces just show first message

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a strange problem. I'm using JSF 2.2 + Primefaces + Bootstrap. When i click in save button a validation is called and if any error occurrs a exception in throw and a message is showed to user. See my codes:

My button to call action in ManagedBean:

```
<h:commandLink
            action="#{cc.attrs.managedBeanName.salvarAndRedirecionar()}"
            styleClass="btn btn-default" value="Salvar">
            <i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i>
        </h:commandLink>
```

My ManagedBean action:

```
public String salvarAndRedirecionar(){
    salvar();
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isValidationFailed()){
        return goToLastPage() + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }else{
        return "";
    }
    }

public void salvar() {
    beforeSave();


    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isValidationFailed()){
        return;
    }

    try {   
        bean = (Bean) getUtil().save(bean);
        addInfoMessage("Registro salvo com sucesso");
        afterSave();
    } catch (BException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addErrorMessageValidationFailed(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addErrorMessageValidationFailed((new StringBuilder()).append("Erro ao salvar. ")
            .append(e.getMessage()).toString());
    }
    return;
    }
```

Imagine i have the following: Car, that have wheels and have colors. Wheels and colors are mandatory and validation grantee that. If i fill car information without wheels and colors i should got message:

"Car need wheels". Because the first validation is about wheels. So i fill wheels and try save again (without colors now). the next message should be: "Car need colors". But nothing is showed, just on IDE CONSOLE (eclipse).

Don't have any error in browser console. How can i fix this ?

**EDIT 1:**

When i try to use commandButton from primefaces, everything works. Look:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.managedBeanName.salvarAndRedirecionar()}" value="salvar" />
```

I'm using JSF commandButton because of bootstrap.

Comment: You forgot to show how you're showing/updating the messages. Given the fact that you're seeing a warning in the console (did you carefully read it?), this just means that you didn't instruct JSF to show/update the message component(s).

Comment: I fixed the problem, thanks anyway. I simple added "<f:ajax execute="@form" />" in h:commandButton.